# position:absolute; Making links not work in my div?

Tags: php, html, css

This is the div's CSS
http://pastebin.com/y2QAPUaH

Basically the links inside the DIV do not work, i have gone through my whole CSS code and narrowed it down to this line position:absolute;

This is a code of the link im trying to make work. LINE15
http://pastebin.com/R6Rth4vM

Comment: I see no links in the code provided.

Comment: Sorry, http://pastebin.com/R6Rth4vM Line 15

Comment: Did you try moving the <a> inside the <h1><em>... ?

Comment: I have indeed. both do not work. is it the way my divs are layed out?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but just a bit of advice: you should add `border-radius` and `box-shadow`, seeing as all new browsers will support CSS3 very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a long shot but I've seen it before where the comment will "comment out" the closing tag so it doesn't actually close:

Change this:

```
<?php // TRY ADDING A LINK TO <EM> YOUR MANAGER</EM> ?>
```

To this:

```
<?php /* TRY ADDING A LINK TO <EM> YOUR MANAGER</EM>*/ ?>
```